# How to read a file from authenticated network share or UNC path from an ASP.Net Core web application hosted on IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, unc, network-share

I have a UNC/network share(Windows FSX) and I would like my ASP.Net Core Web application to read the files from this network share. I tried to use SimpleImpersonation nuget package, however it seems to be deprecated. How to read the files from network share in .Net core?
This is what I tried so far -

```
var credentials = new UserCredentials(uncPath, userName, password);
var result = WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(credentials, () => {
      return _fileSystem.File.ReadAllText($"\\\\{uncPath}\\test.txt");
});
```

Comment: Asking what's _the best way_ isn't a good idea on this site. We don't like opinion. I suggest that you rephrase the question to get rid of "best way". Instead, phrase it as "I'm trying to do this, here's my code, but, these are the problems I'm having..."

Comment: Thanks @Flydog57. I have amended my question now

Comment: I don't know the answer. Another suggestion, show some of your code, even if it's non-working. Good luck